# Cannot Build in Visual Studio Express VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, build

I have errors as follow:

> Error 11  Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\programname.exe" to
>   "bin\Debug\programname.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Can someone tell me how to solve it step by step?

Many thanks.

Comment: have you got your program open that you are creating without visual studio debugging it?

Answer (score 5):

Something has a lock on the executable file, so visual studio cannot replace the exe file on disk.

1. Are you running your exe? If so, just close it
2. Try restarting visual studio
3. Try restarting your machine
4. If that fails you need to use Microsoft/SysInternals Process Explorer to find out what is locking your file

Edit: The only reason I can think of that would still cause this issue after 1,2 and 3 is that this is a windows service exe that is starting up when windows starts up, so you need to stop the service in the service manager

Comment: Can you teach me how to use  Microsoft/SysInternals Process Explorer to find out what is going on? Many thanks.

Comment: That is another question for the SuperUser site (and has probably been asked already)

Comment: Justin in 99% cases first step 1,2,3 will fix it. Are you sure you rebooted computer. Not put to sleep and wake up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the file "bin\Debug\programname.exe" is locked by Visual Studio (VS) itself.

When VS is open, and I can not manually delete file "bin\Debug\programname.exe". So I close VS, after that the file can be deleted.

By deleting the old file, the problem is resolved. VS and can build new object without error.

Comment: This is why the other answer said to restart Visual Studio. It happens to me often when I am running my code and I change something in it, I cannot rebuild the project until I quit Studio and do back again.